# Unable to copy fast a file to clipboard in a Linux computer

Tags: linux, clipboard

I have not yet found an easy solution to copy your file to a clipboard in Linux, similarly as in Mac by

```
cat file | pbcopy
```

I tried to use the following command in Vim unsuccessfully

```
:copy 1,9999999
```

to copy the file.

**How can you copy a file fast to your clipboard in Linux** such that you can then paste it to dpaste?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to xsel and xclip already mentioned there is also [uclip](http://www.typo.co.il/~mooffie/uclip/). From the manual page description:

*uclip  is  a  command-line  interface to the X clipboard. It either copies text,
from FILE or from stdin, to the X clipboard, or prints the X clipboard  to  std-
out.   uclip  supports Unicode and is locale-aware (in contrast to other similar
utilities).  uclip was written using Qt.*

Update: Apparently uclip was not such a good recommendation because it currently does not work for copying, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741129/what-is-the-minimum-amount-of-tweaking-needed-to-get-qclipboardsettext-to-wor) for the problem description (and hopefully a solution some day?).

Comment: This is an excellent link for the tips about the commands: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/

Answer (score 13):

does [xclip](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/xclip-linux-insert-files-command-output-intoclipboard/) suits you?

Comment: Yes, but simply calling `xclip` doesn't do it by default. If I append it with the following options the `-sel clip` or `-selection clipboard` then I can paste the output to my browser etc..
`echo "http://superuser.com/" | xclip -sel clip`, alt-tab to chrome, ctrl+l, ctrl+v, enter... vola!
P.S. I don't know if xsel has similar options to make it work. By default it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

The Linux equivalent of `pbcopy` is `xclip`.

Answer (score 3):

Try [xsel](http://www.vergenet.net/~conrad/software/xsel/). It does wonders, but it doesn't really work with the clipboard, but rather with the X selection buffer.

cat file | xsel

and then you can click the mouse wheel to paste the contents.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning xsel. It raised me another problem: how to configure Mackbook touchpad to understand the mouse wheel button. I need get the xmod code first for the button.

Comment: What's the point of using keyboard commands to copy something if you need a mouse to paste it?? O.O